IntelliSense not working with extra libraries in Monaco Editor with Angular 17
I'm developing an Angular 17 application using the Monaco Editor with the ngx-monaco-editor-v2 package. While the editor works fine in TypeScript mode, I'm unable to get IntelliSense to recognize extra libraries or custom classes that I define. Specifically, I want to use a custom class Car with a method myMethod() in my code, but IntelliSense does not suggest this class or its methods.
I attempted to add the extra library using the monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib method. Here’s the relevant part of my code:
monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib(`
    declare class Car {
        myMethod(): void;
    }
`, "Car");

I also set the compiler options for TypeScript as follows:
monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.setCompilerOptions({
    target: monaco.languages.typescript.ScriptTarget.ES5,
    module: monaco.languages.typescript.ModuleKind.CommonJS,
    allowJs: true,
    checkJs: true,
});

Despite these efforts, when I type const instance = new Car(); in the editor, I do not see any IntelliSense suggestions for Car or its methods. I expected that after adding the extra library, IntelliSense would recognize the Car class and provide suggestions for its methods.
Additional Information
Here’s a snippet of my component code for context:
CodeComponent.component.html
<ngx-monaco-editor
  [options]="editorOptions"
  [(ngModel)]="code"
  (onInit)="onEditorInit($event)"
></ngx-monaco-editor>

CodeComponent.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-code',
  templateUrl: './code.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./code.component.scss'],
})
export class CodeComponent implements OnInit {
  code: string = `
    const instance = new Car();
    instance.myMethod();
  `;

  editorOptions = {
    theme: 'vs-dark',
    language: 'typescript',
    automaticLayout: true,
  };

  // Monaco Editor Initialization
  onEditorInit(editor: monaco.editor.IStandaloneCodeEditor): void {
      monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib(`
          declare class Car {
              myMethod(): void;
          }
      `, "Car");

      console.log("getExtraLibs", monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.getExtraLibs());

      monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.setCompilerOptions({
        target: monaco.languages.typescript.ScriptTarget.ES5,
        module: monaco.languages.typescript.ModuleKind.CommonJS,
        allowJs: true,
        checkJs: true,
    });
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {}
}

package.json
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "^17.3.0",
  "@angular/common": "^17.3.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "^17.3.0",
  "@angular/core": "^17.3.0",
  "@angular/forms": "^17.3.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.3.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.3.0",
  "@angular/router": "^17.3.0",
  "monaco-editor": "^0.52.2",
  "ngx-monaco-editor-v2": "^18.1.0",
  "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
  "tslib": "^2.3.0",
  "zone.js": "~0.14.3"
}

main.ts
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';


(window as any).MonacoEnvironment = {
  getWorkerUrl: function (workerId: string, label: string) {
    return './assets/monaco/min/vs/base/worker/workerMain.js';
  },
};





platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));


